# trying to register GCP Cloud DNS with a GoDaddy domain

Tags: google-app-engine, networking, google-cloud-platform, dns, cloud

I am currently trying to point my **Cloud DNS** instance at a domain name that I recently purchased of GoDaddy. I created a record A, **CNAME** record and changed the **NS** records on GoDaddy to the ones created by **Google Cloud DNS**. It still is not pointing to the domain even after waiting a certain amount of time. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is “a certain amount of time? It came take several days for changes to name servers to update globally.

Comment: when creating your A record presumably you did something like `("Hostname": "@", "TTL": 300, "Type": "A", "Data": [ip_address_for_gcp_server])`. if you're certain you have the GCP server's IP Address correct, look at what you set the TTL to (it's in seconds) that could be the source of your delay.

Comment: I would try to follow this (https://medium.com/@prashantapaudel/gcp-cloud-dns-transfer-your-godaddy-dns-to-google-cloud-dns-with-a-website-hosted-in-compute-bc407707c315) and see if it still does not work.